# How to sort a bi-dimensional javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
var global=[];
var value=[50,1,4,29];
var title=["d","b","c","a"];

title.forEach(function(title,i) {
    global[title]=value[i];
})
```

I would like to sort the global array by value but I can't figure out how.

I precise I can't use any library jquery,underscore...

thanks !

the goal is to know what object has the less value.
a,b,c,d have values 50,1,4,29

I can sort values but how to know what's the name associated to this value ?

Comment: Please show the expected result.

Comment: `global` isn't being used as an array. It's being used as an object (key-value store, map, hash table...) - hence, it's inherently unordered.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `global[]` correctly as an array in your loop. You can't reference array items with `[title]`, you can either `push` to the array `global.push(value[i])` or use `global[i] = value[i]`. If you use either of these methods you can just call 'global.sort()' to sort the array which will give you `[1, 29, 4, 50]`. If you want to use the array as multidimensional, you need to change your loop to something like this:

```
title.forEach(function(title,i) {
    global[i] = {};
    global[i][title]=value[i];
})
```

which will give you `[Object { d=50}, Object { b=1}, Object { c=4}, Object { a=29}]`

If you want to sort this you could use sort which takes a function in which you can write your custom sorter but I don't think you can use this as all your keys are different. If all your keys were the same, say `'value'` ,i.e `[Object { value=50}, Object { value=1}, Object { value=4}, Object { value=29}]` , you could do:

```
global.sort(function(a,b) {
    return parseInt(a.value, 10) - parseInt(b.value, 10);
});
```

but this can't be applied to your array since all the keys are different.

Comment: well thanks but how could I address this problem ? it seems a really simple problem but I can't figure it out how to resolve it simply.

Comment: I thought it was a clear answer, what part are you having problems understanding with?